# How do I pass an Object between Web Pages through POST in PHP?

Tags: php, object, html

Is it possible to pass an Object through a Hidden Field in an HTML Form using $_POST and retrieve that Object on the page that the form links to?

On the first page, I have a form like the one below:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../Model/player.php'; // To Enable Creation of a New Player Object

$playerName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'playerName');
$playerNumber = 1;

$player = new player($playerName, $playerNumber);

if (isset($player))
{
  echo '<p>Successfully created your player!</p><br>';
?>

<form class="viewStats" action="../View/displayPlayerStatsView.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="playerObject" value="<?php echo $player; ?>">
  <input type="submit" value="View Your Player's Stats">
</form>

<?php
  }
?>
```

And on the second (receiving) page, I have code like the code below:

```
session_start();
require_once '../Model/player.php'; // To Use Player Object

$player = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'playerObject'); // ERROR: Thinks the Player Object is a string.
```

My error seems to be that the receiving page that retrieves the 'playerObject' from the $_POST array is acting like the Object is a string.

Can anyone give me guidance on how to pass an Object from one page to another using the $_POST array?  Is this even possible?
Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**
Based on suggestions to serialize the Object, I now am getting the following errors:

If I change my code on the first (sending) page to:

```
$playerSerial = serialize((object) $player);
<form class="viewStats" action="../View/displayPlayerStatsView.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="playerObject" value="<?php echo $playerSerial; ?>">
      <input type="submit" value="View Your Player's Stats">
</form>
```

and change the code on the second (receiving) page to:

```
$playerSerial = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'playerObject');
print_r($playerSerial);
$player = unserialize($playerSerial);
```

then the output I get from `print_r($playerSerial);` is `O:6:`, which I know is incorrect since the object has properties holding a player's name, number, health, strength, etc.

The `require_once '../Model/player.php';` code exists in both PHP files, and it comes right at the top of both before any other code is executed.

Comment: It's funny, but everything you get through POST is a string, something to do with the way http works. You'd have to serialise it, and unserialize it at the receiving end; but surely better to simply use session for something like this

Comment: if it's sent over the web embedded in a request, it's a string. That's the way http works. You can always serialize objects, on code images, etc. and send them that way, but that's basically just converting them to a string in a way that you can convert them back after. Short answer: no. Long answer: whatever attributes you want to send, send those values as strings, and on the other end new up another object that has the same values

Comment: For the record, I typed that before seeing @MarkBaker's comment - funny how similar the first lines are

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a few additions and corrections:

```
<?php 

//... your previous code

$player = serialize($player);
?>

<form class="viewStats" action="../View/displayPlayerStatsView.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="playerObject" value="<?php echo $player; ?>">
  <input type="submit" value="View Your Player's Stats">
</form>
```

Use the serialize() function to create a string that can be passed to your other page which you can unserialize() as follows:

secondPage.php:

```
$player = $_POST['playerObject'];
$player = unserialize($player);
```

Also, you forgot to use echo here:

change

```
value="<?php $player ?>"
```

to

```
value="<?php echo $player; ?>"
```

Comment: I made the changes exactly as suggested.  I have another error: the serialization/unserialization is not working.  I get errors from PHP saying: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 4 bytes in C:\xampp\htdocs\BattleRoyale\View\displayPlayerStatsView.php on line 12
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0006 135672 {main}( ) ..\displayPlayerStatsView.php:0
2 0.0013 163088 unserialize ( ) ..\displayPlayerStatsView.php:12

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function displayPlayerStats() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\BattleRoyale\View\displayPlayerStatsView.php on line 26

Comment: If I perform `$playerSerial = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'playerObject');
print_r($playerSerial);
$player = unserialize($playerSerial);` the output I get from `print_r($playerSerial);` is **O:6:**, which I know is incorrect since the object has properties holding a player's name, number, health, strength, _etc._

Comment: @TechAus10 do you have `require_once '../Model/player.php'; // To Enable Creation of a New Player Object` in the other file as well?

Comment: Yes, the `require_once '../Model/player.php';` code exists in both PHP files, and it comes right at the top of both before any other code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself into serialization: the process of making a string from the object, which can in future be deserialized from the string back to object.

Some docs, which could be useful for you:

[PHP - How object serialize/unserialize works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873395/php-how-object-serialize-unserialize-works)

http://php.net/manual/ru/oop4.serialization.php

http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/classes_objects/serialization.html