# PHP unserialization after changing class definition

Tags: php, serialization

I serialized an object of PHP class in Laravel. Afterwards, I changed the class definition adding a new method and when I unserialize the old object and make a call to that newly implemented method, it works.

I wonder why and how?

Comment: Look at a serialized class intance, and you'll see that it contains only the class name and the property values, not the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - How object serialize/unserialize works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873395/php-how-object-serialize-unserialize-works)

Answer (score 5):

Because serialization process keeps only state of the objects (fields) but not your methods with implementation.